# Pdf generation in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am currently working in a small project. I am trying to generate a pdf using `ionic2+angular2(typescript)` in my android phone. I am using pdfMake.

Here is my code:

```
getPdf() {


var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };

     pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBuffer((buffer) => {
     var utf8 = new Uint8Array(buffer); // Convert to UTF-8...
     let binaryArray = utf8.buffer; // Convert to Binary...

     let fileName = "file.pdf";
     let saveDir = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;

       File.createFile(saveDir, fileName, true).then((fileEntry) => {
         fileEntry.createWriter((fileWriter) => {
             fileWriter.onwriteend = () => {
               let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                 message: 'PDF gerado com sucesso! Abrindo arquivo...',
                 duration: 2000,
                 position: 'middle'
               });
               toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
                 cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                   saveDir+fileName,
                   'application/pdf');
               });
               //this.navCtrl.present(toast);
               toast.present();
             };
             fileWriter.onerror = (e) => {
                 console.log('file writer - error event fired: ' + e.toString());
             };
             fileWriter.write(binaryArray);
         });
       });
     });
  }
```

It is showing error in `createWriter` as property `createWriter` doesn't exist on type `FileEntry|FileError`.

Comment: your code works fine

Answer (score 0):

Might be problem with import statements

```
import * as pdfmake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
```

add this to your index.html file

```
 <body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  <script src='pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
  <script src='pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>


</body>
```